# How can I get the status of an order through Eventbrite API

Tags: registration, payment, eventbrite

I would like to connect the registration on my site with an event application on Eventbrite. My goal would be the following:

1. The user register for the event
2. After the registration, the user will be redirected to my site with the proper ids to be able to create an account for him/her on our side
3. The system creates a user and makes him/her active, if the attandee has paid the ticket(s) (f.e. PayPal), or inactive until they pay it.

My question is that can I get the status of an order somehow via the Eventbrite API?

I see two related parameter(http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/users/user_list_tickets/):

- amount_paid
- status

Thank you for your answer in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work on Eventbrite's API/Platform team, so hopefully I can help you out.

Eventbrite's current version of the API doesn't have a concept around Orders.

The /user_list_tickets method that you're referring to is based around the individual event attendees. So for example, if you collected authentication on behalf of an Eventbrite user and then made a /user_list_tickets call against their account -- you would receive a list of events that they have acquired tickets for. You would not receive a list of orders that have occurred for a specific event.

However, we do have an API method that displays a list of attendees for a specific event (when that event organizer has provided authentication): http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_list_attendees/

In this list of attendees, you'll see "order_type", "amount_paid", and other attributes depending on the way that the event was set up.

Hope this helps!